# R line 'm' does not have 'n' elems in read table

Tags: r

So I'm doing a readtable of some data -

```
salaries.data = read.table(someUrl, header=FALSE, sep=' ', na.strings="?", comment.char='')
plot(salaries.data)
```

I get this error-

```
## Error: line 2 did not have 22 elements
```

This is what the data looks like when I print it in RStudio's console

```
                             V1
1     Y       X1    X2      X3 
2     33.2    3.5    9.0    6.1
3     40.3    5.3   20.0    6.4
4     38.7    5.1   18.0    7.4
5     46.8    5.8   33.0    6.7
6     41.4    4.2   31.0    7.5
7     37.5    6.0   13.0    5.9
8     39.0    6.8   25.0    6.0
9     40.7    5.5   30.0    4.0
10    30.1    3.1    5.0    5.8
11    52.9    7.2   47.0    8.3
12    38.2    4.5   25.0    5.0
13    31.8    4.9   11.0    6.4
14    43.3    8.0   23.0    7.6
15    44.1    6.5   35.0    7.0
16    42.8    6.6   39.0    5.0
17    33.6    3.7   21.0    4.4
18    34.2    6.2    7.0    5.5
19    48.0    7.0   40.0    7.0
20    38.0    4.0   35.0    6.0
21    35.9    4.5   23.0    3.5
22    40.4    5.9   33.0    4.9
23    36.8    5.6   27.0    4.3
24    45.2    4.8   34.0    8.0
25    35.1    3.9   15.0    5.0
```

This table looks well formed - so what's going on?

Comment: except that it is not well formed. What is V1? And don't you have table headers?

Comment: that V1 isn't in the table when I visit the url I'm getting it from...so I'm not sure how that's there? Can I force R to skip that line?

Comment: What`s `someUrl`? Here`s what the data looks like well-formed: `salaries.data = read.table("http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~lsimon/stat501/sp04/data/mathsalaries.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# data from a URL, as per OP's comment
someUrl <- "http://sites.stat.psu.edu/~lsimon/stat501/sp04/data/mathsalaries.txt‌"
salaries.data <- read.table(someUrl, header=TRUE)
plot(salaries.data)
```

Note the `header=TRUE`.